# Telerik MVC Upload files - how to reinitialize if Model.State is invalid

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc, kendo-upload

I have a view which has an upload control placed on it - I only want to actually process the files to upload when the form is completed and valid - in which case I will upload the files.

However - I seem to have problem with either binding the control to an property in the viewmodel passed to the view OR having a the correct property type to pass between the view and the controller.

Comment: It would be helpful to show your code here. Also the title looks like a other question than what you have in the details. Can you explain your question a bit more?

Comment: The problem is that the view returns back a collection with  something like IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files   .   The telerik example of the control for basic usage will show this  http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/upload/index     However the initial files demo - doesnt really show to much about the initialization except that its using a class SessionUploadInitialFilesRepository to set the files.  The fact being that when uploaded the local path may be lost.

Comment: I sort of got around it by adding the files synchronously to a temp location - and then when the main form is submitted it will copy them from the temp location on the server to the final location.   This way if main item (order) is not submitted after the asynchronous upload has taken place then temp files are just overwritten later.    I'd spent too much time messing around with trying to recreate the control with files paths populated when one of the other fields failed validation prior to posting.